# Retrieve last value defined for a tree data in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Product Tier1 Tier2 Tier3   value
 A       ANZ    -     -       2
 A       ANZ    DE    -       3
 A       ANZ    DE    Outlet  9
 B       EMEA   -     -       4
 B       EMEA   IT    -       6
```

I am every time interested in the last value defined for a Product.
For example for Product A i should get the value 9 and for Product B i should get the value 6.

Is it possible i can get result directly using sql query or i load the entire product rows and perform operations in backend code to get the final value. What is more preferable. I am using MYsql.

```
  ANZ       2        
   |
   DE       3
   |
   OUTLET - 9 last defined level value is 9


 EMEA   4
  |
 IT     6
  |
  ?     No value defined so last defined level value is 6
```

cases can be

case 1

```
 Product Tier1 Tier2 Tier3   value
     A       ANZ    -     -       2
     A       ANZ    DE    -       3
     A       ANZ    DE    Outlet  9

Desired result = 9
```

case2

```
     Product Tier1 Tier2 Tier3   value
         A       ANZ    DE    Outlet  9

   Desired result = 9
```

case3

```
    Product Tier1 Tier2 Tier3   value
         A       ANZ    -     -       2
         A       ANZ    DE    Outlet  9

   Desired result = 9
```

case4

```
 Product Tier1 Tier2 Tier3   value
     A       ANZ    -     -       2
     A       ANZ    DE    -       3

   Desired result = 3
```

case5

```
 case4
   Product Tier1 Tier2 Tier3   value
     A       ANZ    -     -       2

 Desired result = 2
```

Comment: do you need product A with value 9 and product B with value 6 so only 2 data, isn't it ?

Comment: So if i say give me the last defined value for Product A , Than i must get 9. Give me the last defined value for Product B , than i get 6. I hope i am clear now.

Comment: How do you know 9 is the latests?

Comment: then my question is how can i know last define ? do you mean  by last insert it to database or biggest value, i'm trying understand your issue here,

Comment: `last` depend on how you `order` the result. What is the ordering criteria here?

Comment: There are only 3 Tier. So I know 9 is the latest because it has Tier3 defined. 3 cannot be latest since for 3 no Tier3 is defined. We can understand the problem like following. Tiers are like levels. I want to get the last defined level value.

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: is the undefined saved as NULL in table?

Comment: @FreddySidauruk I added more description

Comment: @DylanSu If you are asking for Tier values than yes.Tier1, Tier2, Tier3 all can null.

Comment: A solution is provided as ans. pls check if it is what u expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes a solution verified with data provided.

SQL:

```
SELECT
    product,
    tier1,
    tier2,
    tier3,
    value
FROM 
    tbl tbl2
WHERE
    ( tbl2.product, ((tier1 IS NOT NULL) + (tier2 IS NOT NULL ) + (tier3 IS NOT NULL)) ) IN
        (
            SELECT 
                product,
                MAX( (tier1 IS NOT NULL) + (tier2 IS NOT NULL ) + (tier3 IS NOT NULL) ) maxTierCnt
            FROM
                tbl
            WHERE
                tbl.product = tbl2.product
        );
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl;
+---------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| product | tier1 | tier2 | tier3  | value |
+---------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| A       | ANZ   | NULL  | NULL   |     2 |
| A       | ANZ   | DE    | NULL   |     3 |
| A       | ANZ   | DE    | Outlet |     9 |
| B       | EMEA  | NULL  | NULL   |     4 |
| B       | EMEA  | IT    | NULL   |     6 |
+---------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT
    ->     product,
    ->     tier1,
    ->     tier2,
    ->     tier3,
    ->     value
    -> FROM
    ->     tbl tbl2
    -> WHERE
    ->     ( tbl2.product, ((tier1 IS NOT NULL) + (tier2 IS NOT NULL ) + (tier3 IS NOT NULL)) ) IN
    ->         (
    ->             SELECT
    ->                 product,
    ->                 MAX( (tier1 IS NOT NULL) + (tier2 IS NOT NULL ) + (tier3 IS NOT NULL) ) maxTierCnt
    ->             FROM
    ->                 tbl
    ->             WHERE
    ->                 tbl.product = tbl2.product
    ->         );
+---------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| product | tier1 | tier2 | tier3  | value |
+---------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| A       | ANZ   | DE    | Outlet |     9 |
| B       | EMEA  | IT    | NULL   |     6 |
+---------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is this "MAX( (tier1 IS NOT NULL) + (tier2 IS NOT NULL ) + (tier3 IS NOT NULL) ) maxTierCnt". I am curious.

Comment: find the longest chain of tier1-tier2-tier3. which is what you want to filter out.

Comment: SELECT {psa:pk} FROM {TableLevels} as psa 
    {TableLevels} as psaa WHERE
 ({psaa:product}, ((tier1 IS NOT NULL) + ( tier2 IS NOT NULL) + ( tier3 IS NOT NULL)) ) IN 
 (SELECT product, MAX( ( tier1 IS NOT NULL) + ( tier2 IS NOT NULL) + ( tier3 IS NOT NULL)) maxTier FROM psa WHERE {psaa:product}={psa:product})          I tried to implement your query but it results in cannot find (visible) type for alias psa within ... exception. Could you please help me what can be the problem here.

Comment: I didn't understand the query you put in comments. It differs greatly with my original query. My query follows exactly ur original table structure. It should be easily converted to ur implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do what you want:

```
SELECT value
FROM product
WHERE product.Product = 'A'
ORDER BY Tier1 DESC, Tier2 DESC, Tier3 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

…using whatever product you are actually looking for in place of `'A'`, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain this part of your query "ORDER BY Tier1 DESC, Tier2 DESC, Tier3 DESC
LIMIT 1".

Comment: It is based on my assumption that you want the "last" item to be the one with the maximum `Tier3` value among those with the maximum `Tier2` value among those with the maximum `Tier1` value. Sorting by `Tier1` in descending order ensures that the 1st row will have the maximum value for that column. Sorting next by `Tier2` in descending order ensures that the first row will have the maximum value for that column among those with the desired `Tier1 values, etc.  `LIMIT 1` means we just want the first row of that result.

Comment: I see.. well in my case there is no maximum concept. The values dont have to either increasing or decreasing. The values can be even equal or lesser than the value for the previous defined level. But i believe the query should be something similar as you suggested.

Comment: deleted my answer after reading this **The values can be even equal or lesser than the value for the previous defined level** Can you please explain appropriately with a valid example

Comment: In that case, you are not storing enough data to solve your problem. Databases deal with sets (not lists) of records. There is no intrinsic order, so no way to ask for the last-entered record in a group. You could add an auto-incrementing field, so you have something with a value that is always larger for newer records — and then you can sort by that column in descending order.

Comment: @SteveJorgensen Added more cases to understand the problem better.

Comment: So is it just the largest value of `value` for a given product that you're looking for? In that case, all you need is `SELECT MAX(value) FROM product WHERE product.Product = '<whatever>'`.

Answer (score 0):

well i guess you should use sub query like this

```
select * from table where product=(select Product B) and product=(select product A)
```

and this is all query

```
  select * from table where product=('SELECT value FROM product WHERE product.Product = 'A' ORDER BY id_product  DESC LIMIT 1')  and product=('SELECT value FROM product WHERE product.Product = 'b' ORDER BY id_product DESC  LIMIT 1')
```

not tested but you can use the loggic, hope this help

Edit : i use edit id_product (consider it auto increment ya) so you can get this is right data

Comment: I am sorry but this is incorrect, as he needs the **latest** value and not the **maximum** value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Product, Tier1, Tier2, Tier3
FROM (
  SELECT Product, Tier1, Tier2, Tier3,
         @rn := IF(@p = Product, @rn + 1,
                   IF(@p := Product, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @p = '') AS vars
  ORDER BY 
     Product, 
     IF(Tier3 = '-', 1, 0),
     IF(Tier2 = '-', 1, 0),
     IF(Tier1 = '-', 1, 0)) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

The `ORDER BY` uses conditionals so as to sort records according to the maximum level they are related to.

Using this order, the query determines the greatest-per-group record using variables. `@rn` is 1 for *the first record in every `Product` slice*. Once the product changes, `@rn` is being reset to 1, to start counting for the next slice.

**Note:** You can change conditions `Tierx = '-'` to `Tierx IS NULL`, if `NULL` is used to specify an empty level instead of a `'-'`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90deb/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
select y.Product, y.value
from (
    select 
        Product, 
        max(case 
            when Tier3  is not null then 3 
            when Tier2  is not null then 2 
            when Tier1  is not null then 1
        else 0  end) max_Tier
    from tbl
    group by Product
) x
join (
    select 
        Product, 
        case 
            when Tier3  is not null then 3 
            when Tier2  is not null then 2 
            when Tier1  is not null then 1
        else 0  end Tier,
        value
    from tbl
) y
on x.Product = y.Product
and y.Tier = x.max_Tier
```